# retrieve echoing database using php and doing some math with keyup function won't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I still new at this JavaScript thing, and try to do something with **HTML**, **PHP** and **JavaScript**.

so I have a table to display estimate labor from database, and the real labor that I should to input, what I really tried here is to get the gap between estimate labor and the real labor

just like so:

============================================================

estLabor || realLabor || the Gap|| reason why there is a gap

============================================================

the formula is estLabor - realLabor = laborGap.

What I had had to accomplish is a failure, this is the code:

some PHP before the form started:

```
<?php
$sqlReport = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `recordProd` WHERE `force_flag` = 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlReport, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $estLabor = $row['labor_estimation'];
?>
```

**HTML**:

```
<tr>
    <td>Labor</td>
    <td id="estLabor"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="laborInput" id="realLabor"></td>
    <td><span class="gaps laborGap"></span></td>
    <td><textarea name="reasonLabor"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
var estLabor = <?php echo $estLabor; ?>;
var realLabor = document.getElementById("realLabor").value;
$("#estLabor").html(estLabor);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#realLabor').keyup(function() {
        var a = $('td#estLabor').val();
        var b = $('input#realLabor').val();
        $('span.laborGap').text(a - b);
        console.log('var a = ', a, ' var b = ', b);
    });
});
</script>
```

Things I've got from console is

> var a =    var b =  3

question is simple, how to do this? retrieve from database and doing math in the precise time I put numbers in the **TextField** and getting result for the span of laborGap.

Comment: `td`s don't have `value`, they have `textContent`.

Comment: @Teemu i just tried something dumb, i changed val() function with textContent() function and getting this warning: TypeError: $(...).textContent is not a function[Learn More]. LoL. I didn't know what u meant, but i tried this and it doing good, var estLaborVal = document.getElementById("estLabor").textContent;

Comment: Umh ... the native `textContent` is read by `.text()` method in jQuery.

Comment: @teemu i'll learn. thx to u anyway

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are going wrong on substraction,

You can do something like this to your formula:

```
      $( "#a" ).keyup(function() {
      var a = $('#a').val();
      var b = $('#b').val();
      var c = parseInt(b) - parseInt(a);
      $('#c').val(c);
     });
```

For detail you can check my [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z4dwc12p/1/)

Comment: u don't understand what i asking for. @teemu just answered the question, thx.

Answer (score 0):

td doesn't have any value, it's all text. so using textContent instead of val

in outer function to describe variable:

`var estLaborVal = document.getElementById("estLabor").textContent;`

and fix varible inside the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#realLabor').keyup(function() {
        var a = estLaborVal;
        var b = $('input#realLabor').val();
        $('span.laborGap').text(a - b);
        console.log('var a = ', a, ' var b = ', b);
    });
});
```

it doing well, thx for @Teemu

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing JavaScript and JQuery so here is a full JQuery function to help you.

You can put your `$estLabor` variable in `<label>` like this ,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#realLabor').keyup(function() {
        var a = $('#estLabor').text();
        var b = $('#realLabor').val();
        $('span.laborGap').text(a - b);
        console.log('var a = ', a, ' var b = ', b);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>Labor</td>
  <td>
    <label id="estLabor">
      10 <!-- Put <?php echo $estLabor; ?> here -->
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="laborInput" id="realLabor">
  </td>
  <td><span class="gaps laborGap"></span></td>
  <td>
    <textarea name="reasonLabor"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```